# Как разобрать многомерный массив на элементы?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

есть многомерный массив такого вида - `array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "ru" [1]=> string(2) "he" [2]=> string(2) "en" } }`.  Как разобрать многомерный массив на элементы? И вообще есть ли универсальная функция которая разбирает массивы любого уровня вложенности?

Для простых массивов использую такой код, но такой массив (`array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "ru" [1]=> string(2) "he" [2]=> string(2) "en" } }`) он уже не обрабатывает:

```
foreach ($answer as $key => $value) {
            for ($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++) { 
                if($value[$i] == 'call'){
                    $output .= "<li>Звонки</li>";
                }elseif($value[$i] == 'sms'){
                    $output .= "<li>SMS</li>";
                }elseif($value[$i] == 'whatsapp'){
                    $output .= "<li>WhatsApp</li>";
                }elseif($value[$i] == 'viber'){
                    $output .= "<li>Viber</li>";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать `foreach` в `foreach`

Comment: Честно говоря не понятно какой у вас массив (т.к. в описании одно, а в коде `foreach` другое), вот если бы вы его показали, скажем через `print_r($answer)` , получили бы ответ!

Comment: Что Вы должны получить на выходе после разбора массива?

Comment: @RaZik список элементов html - ul, ol

Comment: @eprivalov1 Мы вам не сможем помочь с правильным перебором, пока вы не покажете что перебирать, покажите массив в примере - `print_r($answer)` (если какую либо информацию не хотите показывать, удалите) и можно не все строки, главное чтобы вы показали всю структуру массива!

Comment: @RifmaMan первое, что мне нужно сделать - разобрать массив вида array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "ru" [1]=> string(2) "he" [2]=> string(2) "en" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите перебрать массив вида `array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "ru" [1]=> string(2) "he" [2]=> string(2) "en" } }` вам следует использовать `foreach` в `foreach`:

```html
$countries = array(
  array("ru", "he", "en")
);

foreach($countries as $country) {
  foreach($country as $country_code) {
    echo $country_code;
  }
}
```